# Вызов Linux из загрузчика Windows(BCD)

Tags: windows, linux

Уважаемые знатоки!

На USB-диске первый раздел с Windows 8, второй с Linux. Загрузчик Linux установлен во второй раздел. Как сделать, чтобы загрузчик Windows вызывал Linux из 2-го раздела?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Надо делать наоборот. Ставить в MBR Linux-загрузчик (обычно GRUB) и в него добавлять винду.

PS: Ну, то есть, наверное, это теоретически как-то можно сделать путём каких-нибудь невероятных усилий заставить думать виндозный загрузчик, что GRUB - это винда. Но думаю, что если вам для дела надо, а не баловства ради, то лучше не пытаться так делаьть. Получится сложно и ненадёжно.